# hottowel nuget with entity framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, hottowel

I'm trying to get hottowel installed via nuget in my german visual studio 2013 mvc application.

I get this error:

Install-Package : Error during the update from "EntityFramework 6.0.1" auf "EntityFramework 5.0.0". No version of "EntityFramework.de, 
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" found, which are compatible with "EntityFramework 5.0.0"

It just says, that the new authentication thing called "identity" uses entityframework features which are not compatible with the needed entity framework 5 for hottowel.

How can I solve this? I want to use the new identity features as well as hottowel.

Regards

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you find any help?

Comment: I just got the HotTowel Template to load (via new project).  If you like I can let you know how.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for watching my course! Some of you have let me know that there are some issues with the newest WebApi NuGet packages. Once these are resolved (coordinating with Microsoft and Breeze folks) I will let you all know. In the meantime, here is the workaround which is quite simple:

For now, the easiest thing to do is install the nuget packages in this order. I am working with the Breeze team and the ASP.NET team to make this easier soon :)

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -version 4.0.30506.0
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata -version 4.0.30506.0
>
> Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact -version 4.3.6
>
> Install-Package HotTowel.angular -pre
>
> Install-Package HotTowel.angular.breeze -pre

The first 3 ask it to use the WebApi 4.0.30506 ... which makes it all work. Once I get confirmation from the Breeze team on some changes and check them with the Web Api team, I will update this and let everyone know how to make it work with Web API v2.

Thanks again for your support!

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard, there is a breeze package that will let the newer versions off the first 4 installs work together. Only  `HotTowel.Angular.Breeze` needs to updated to OData 5.0

Comment: The package i'm talking about is Breeze.WebApi2.EF6

Comment: Yep. That package was just created 2 days ago while I was traveling. I need to test versions of my packages that work with both v1 and v2 today. It may be easy, but I also have a day job :)

Comment: Good luck:) I hope it's coming out soon. I'm aware of the fact that 'spare time' is almost always the main problem

Comment: John Papa, is there a way I can reach you, to discuss some things about the course and some problems I'm facing.

Comment: Pluralsight has a LiveFyre discussion page for each course. thats a good way to discuss it and I check there regularly.

Comment: John, I am just starting to use HotTowel.Angular and ran into this issue: Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.1.2' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'.

 Do the steps above to resolve this issue still apply? If not, please suggest the new steps to resolve. Thanks!

Comment: The above steps did not work for me. Any suggestions to resolve, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Issue resolved! I followed the steps in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764502/system-web-http-reference-defaults-to-4-0-version-no-matter-how-i-try) to resolve my issues. Posting here in hopes somewhere will find it useful.