# is there an updated version for Hottowel.angular.breeze -pre install package?

Tags: nuget, breeze, hottowel

i tried installing this package and got the following error.

```
Install-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.30506' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2' that is compatible with 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.30506'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package HotTowel.Angular.Breeze -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

any help is appreciated,
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [hottowel nuget with entity framework 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525619/hottowel-nuget-with-entity-framework-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for watching my course! Some of you have let me know that there are some issues with the newest WebApi NuGet packages. Once these are resolved (coordinating with Microsoft and Breeze folks) I will let you all know. In the meantime, here is the workaround which is quite simple:

For now, the easiest thing to do is install the nuget packages in this order. I am working with the Breeze team and the ASP.NET team to make this easier soon :)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -version 4.0.30506.0
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata -version 4.0.30506.0
Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact -version 4.3.6

install-Package HotTowel.angular -pre
Install-Package HotTowel.angular.breeze -pre
```

The first 3 ask it to use the WebApi 4.0.30506 ... which makes it all work. Once I get confirmation from the Breeze team on some changes and check them with the Web Api team, I will update this and let everyone know how to make it work with Web API v2.

Thanks again for your support!

**UPDATE**

You can now use EF6, Web API v2 with Breeze 1.4.5.  Just install HotTowel.

```
Install-Package HotTowel.Angular.Breeze -pre
```

Comment: Thanks John for a) replying, and b) coordinating with both the Web API team and Breeze. I look forward to seeing your updates.

Comment: Not work for HotTowel Durandal-Knockout. The same error occurs during HotTowel install. Who can show the needed steps for Non angular scenario?