# System.Web.Http reference defaults to 4.0 version no matter how I try

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, breeze, nuget-package

I am using the BreezeApi NuGet package in my project. It is in Visual Studio 2013.

I get this error.

> Error    41    Assembly 'Breeze.WebApi2, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6085f1a45e2ac59' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I don't know why my project keeps referencing the 4.0 version. Things I tried:

1. I removed the reference of system.web.http 4.0 from my project and browsed to the 5.0 DLL file location. As soon as I add it and come back to Solution Explorer, right click on the system.web.http dll, it is showing 4.0.0.0.
2. I added assembly binding in web.config like below

   ```
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
   ```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What version of the framework are you targeting?  Also, if you expand References, click on System.Web.Http, and view the Properties window (F4), you should see a Path property that will give you some insight into where it's coming from (e.g. D:\Projects\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.1.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll).  Does yours come from Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what I did to solve an issue very similar to yours:

> Error 2   Assembly 'Breeze.WebApi2, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f6085f1a45e2ac59' uses 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  c:\Repos\SPACodeCamper\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.12\lib\Breeze.WebApi2.dll CC.Web

I got this error while doing the course [Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 1](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze) by John Papa. It happened on step 3.15 after adding the `Breeze` Web API Controller to CC.Web.

To solve it we need to update the following NuGet Packages. I used NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2013:

1. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client from 5.0.0 to 5.1.2
2. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core from 5.0.0 to 5.1.2
3. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost from 5.0.0 to 5.1.2
4. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData from 5.0.0 to 5.1.2 (this one I had to restart Visual Studio to complete the installation)

Updating the NuGet packages above will take care of bumping `System.Web.Http`'s version to the correct one, in this case `5.1.0.0`.

Comment: hehehe a comment from @John Papa! Isn't the internet so cool!? BTW, here's a readme with additional changes I had to do along the course: https://github.com/leniel/SPACodeCamper/blob/master/README.txt it's still work in Progress at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is given [here](http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2014/05/10/load-file-assembly-system-web-http-running-custom-tool-typelite/).

You have to update the NuGet packages. The easiest one is update-package in the NuGet packet manager console.

Be aware of other dependencies that might break.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating all my packages from NuGet.